# Charts Display ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, charts

I'm new to ASP.net and I currently have a display issue with ASP charts:

Let's say I want to diplay two charts. I have the following code in my default.aspx file (code generated with the toolbox):

```
    <div>
    <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">
        <series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series1">
            </asp:Series>
        </series>
        <chartareas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </chartareas>
    </asp:Chart>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
    </div>
    <div>
    <asp:Chart ID="Chart2" runat="server">
        <series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series1">
            </asp:Series>
        </series>
        <chartareas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </chartareas>
    </asp:Chart>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" Text="Button" />
    </div>
```

And the behindcode in the default.aspx.cs file:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double[] yValues = { 71.15, 23.19, 5.66 };
        string[] xValues = { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC" };
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double[] yValues = { 71.15, 23.19, 5.66 };
        string[] xValues = { "DDD", "EEE", "FFF" };
        Chart2.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);
    }
```

My problem is that when I click on the Button1, my first chart appears. But then when I click on the Button2, the first chart disappear and the second one appears.

I would like to keep both charts displayed!

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

Set `EnableViewState ="true"` for both Charts

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" EnableViewState ="true">
```